# Need aria label to be announced upon executing function

Tags: javascript, angular, accessibility, wai-aria

```
<div class="accordion-header" (click)="toggleExpandCollapse()" tabindex="0" (keyup.enter)="toggleExpandCollapse()">

   <span class="accordion-title" role="button" [attr.aria-label]="toggled ? menuItemHeader.label + 'expanded' : menuItemHeader.label + 'collapsed'">`{{ menuItemHeader.label }}</span>`
```

I currently have this accordion element which can be collapsed or expanded. When it is collapsed, the screen reader will announce it as collapsed, and same if it is expanded.
All I need now for the accessibility user is when they hit the enter key to expand the accordion, screen reader should announce "expanded".
So I need that (keyup.enter)="toggleExpandCollapse()" to announce aria-label="expanded". How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

`aria-*` attributes are classified into two groups: states and properties.

A [state](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#dfn-state) is something that can change, usually because of a user interaction, such as `aria-checked`.

A [property](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#dfn-property) is something that defines the "nature" of the object and its value rarely changes, such as `aria-required`.

When a **property** changes, there is no notification to the user that something changed.

When a **state** changes, the screen reader will announce the change.

[`aria-label`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-label) is a **property**.  Its value will **not** be announced when you make a change.

[`aria-expanded`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-expanded) is a **state**.  Its value **will** be announced when you make a change.

I would recommend that you not change the `aria-label` of your object but instead set `aria-expanded` and toggle its value between true and false.

Answer (score 0):

A screen reader will read "Expanded" or "Collapsed" automatically based on the status of the [aria-expanded](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#aria-expanded) attribute. That is the attribute you want to toggle.